# how to put a progress bar for jquery file upload plugin?

Tags: jquery-ui, progress-bar

I am using the plugin https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

I have done basic setup given on https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin

And I have added a drop box using the instructions on https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Drop-zone-effects

All of this is working. Now I need to implement the progress bar. I am able to display progress information using https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Extended-progress-information. But I do not know how to implement a progress bar

I do not want to use flash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used jquery-UI progress bar for the purpose. It is simple to use and works for me